# Dojo TextButton not able to submit

Tags: html, button, dojo

I am creating a simple text button with `xwt.widget.form.TextButton` and I have wrapped it within a form, but I am unable to make the button submit when I click on it. Here is the example code:

```
<form action="add.jsp" method="post">
    <button dojoType="xwt.widget.form.TextButton" id="submit" baseClass="defaultButton" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Are you unable to pass the `type` property to a Dojo TextButton? It works properly if I don't specify the `dojoType`, but then I lose all of the style elements for the button.

Comment: Cut and pasted your code, worked for me, well except the 404 since i dont have add.jsp :)  http://jsfiddle.net/G4TM2/

Comment: @tik27, that example isn't even using Dojo. @raphnguyen, what is the `xwt.widget.form.TextButton`? It's not something that's included in Dojo so without the code of it we cannot check what's wrong.